# Unpack dict to function

Tags: python

I have two functions:

```
def fill_full_name(self, first_name, last_name):
    self.__first_name_txt_bx.type(first_name)
    self.__last_name_txt_bx.type(last_name)
```

```
def fill_first_name(self, first_name):
    self.__first_name_txt_bx.type(first_name)
```

I need to pass them data from a dictionary:

```
FULL_NAME = {"first_name": "Donald", "last_name": "Black"}
```

in the first case i can do like this:

```
card_registration_form.fill_full_name(**FULL_NAME )
```

What is the most pythonic way to pass arguments to the second function?
I would like to not specify the key explicitly, as it is the same as the argument name. Is there a way to pass like the first case but not use additional arguments?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Python dictionary access operator `[]` as follows:

```
card_registration_form.fill_first_name(FULL_NAME["first_name"])
```

Comment: I would like to not specify the key explicitly, as it is the same as the argument name. Is there a way to pass like the first case but not use additional arguments?

Comment: Yes, but you would have to add `**kwargs` to the `fill_first_name` function signature, so it can accept other keyword arguments (like last_name).

Comment: @ivan Please update your question if you want to add some extra funcitonality.

Comment: If i specify: "def fill_card_number(self, first_name, **kwargs)" , but I will not use kwargs. Is it a bad practice?

Answer (score 3):

Just use `kwargs`. Inside the function, use whatever keys you need.

```
def foo(**kwargs):
    return kwargs["first_name"]

FULL_NAME = {"first_name": "Donald", "last_name": "Black"}

foo(**FULL_NAME)
# 'Donald'
```